# Can I still create an account on Xbox Live for the Classic Xbox?

Tags: xbox-network, xbox

I recently re-purchased an old Xbox and I would like to try out Xbox Live. Can I still create an account for Xbox Live with my classic Xbox? And if so, how do I do it? I remember you used to go to a store and buy an Xbox Live Starters Kit, I can't imagine those are still available.

Comment: I'd suggest have fun with modding away on that one, a much better purpose than trying to play on the old school Xbox Live games

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Xbox Live is now cancelled for the original Xbox.

They turned it off April 15 2010.

http://news.cnet.com/8301-13772_3-20004670-52.html

Comment: Really? :( that sucks..

Comment: @Lex I expanded my answer a little.

Comment: @michael Yeah, I figured I'd reference the last guys :D

Answer (score 3):

Answering this old question for the curious. Although the other accepted answer is still valid, Microsoft indeed turned Xbox Live off and you'll not be able to connect to official servers anymore.

There are now ways to make the old original Xbox go on an Xbox Live replacement. While there have been local network tricks to play against other players around the world, [Insignia](https://insignia.live/)  will offer anyone with an Xbox (or emulated Xbox) the option to relive Xbox live multiplayer experience. Follow the website instructions to get up and started. for now and probably forever be free. You don't need a credit card nor a "valid" Xbox live activation code (you used to be able to scratch a few months free from the bundled game).

All you need is an original Xbox, modded or unmodded, and a way to run their installer (softmod games or modchip) but you don't need to leave the Xbox modded, it's only used to get your Xbox registered to their service. and the hard disk should not be Null keyed (this is for modders, ways to fix are explained).
Internet connection of course, and you need to change DNS settings on the Xbox.

If you like to save your old or create new Xbox live accounts (that will NOT function yet on Insignia) you can use this awesome tool [here](https://github.com/feudalnate/Original-Xbox-LIVE-Account). It can save and create new Xbox live accounts as if you would have back in the day. Backup for your old accounts or creation for those that wish to play Phantasy Star Online on the original Xbox unmodded in single-player mode.

Another under-development method would be [XombieOnline](https://github.com/XombieOnline/xombie/issues) by Tristan, who also gave a [Defcon talk](https://info.defcon.org/events/48508/)  although I think you'd be better of trying [mborgerson's fork](https://github.com/mborgerson/xombie).

All very technical. I guess most of the curious folks out here might want to try Insignia for now.