# Can you still play PSO Episode I & II on Xbox?

Tags: xbox-network, xbox, phantasy-star-online

I heard that you need a *Xbox Live* account to play **Phantasy Star Online Episode I & II** on Xbox, even for the offline mode.

Unfortunately, the service was shut down for the first Xbox generation ([in 2010-04-15](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/4494/30863)).

I wonder:

- Is it impossible to play this game on the Xbox 1 now?
- Or do those versions that were once activated in *Xbox Live* still work?
- If so, are they bound to the Xbox they were activated on or could you buy an once activated version of PSO Ep. 1 & 2 and play it on your Xbox (which was never connected to *Xbox Live*)?
- Back then, was it sufficient to activate the game once, or would you have to subscribe to the service for as long as you wanted to play? (difference between online and offline mode?)

(I assume you can't play it on Xbox 360, as it is not listed in the [List of Xbox games compatible with Xbox 360](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Xbox_games_compatible_with_Xbox_360).)

Comment: Found a thread about [PSOR (Phantasy Star Online Resurrection)](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/561400-phantasy-star-online-episode-i-and-ii/62989416). The project’s website is http://phantasystaronline.4umotion.com/

Comment: A tutorial (the download links for the gamertag seem to be down, though): https://assemblergames.com/threads/phantasy-star-online-xbox-gamertag.49737/#post-725868

Comment: A discussion about this topic on Reddit: [\[Original Xbox\] PSO ep1&2. Is there anyway to recover it and play?](https://www.reddit.com/r/PSO/comments/egho9k/original_xbox_pso_ep12_is_there_anyway_to_recover/)

Comment: A solution: https://github.com/feudalnate/Original-Xbox-LIVE-Account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to have is an Xbox memory card to do this:

You need to transfer an Xbox Live account to that Xbox in order to play. The reason why you need an Xbox Live account is because the whole serial code was not needed for Xbox it only required that you had Xbox live or an old account.

You have to have a gamertag to play Xbox PSO, even offline. Xbox Live for the original Xbox was shut down years ago so you can't create a gamertag anymore. If you have a means of copying a friends gamertag to your Xbox that can work. If not, you should probably consider playing on a different platform.

Sources: [Sega Forums](http://forums.sega.com/showthread.php?356905-old-XBOX-help-Phantasy-star-Episode-I-II-online) | [Phantasy Star Online Forums](http://www.pso-world.com/forums/showthread.php?t=198856)

Answer (score 0):

There is one other way to play, you need a modded or softmodded Xbox to do this.
There are simple and easy ways to softmod your Xbox but to avoid breaking any rules here, Youtube is your friend here.
You next need to download a offline patched copy of the game, again Google is your friend here.
Burn the copy to a blank dvd-r or tranfer directly to the Xbox HDD.
You should be good here.